# Python/Flask Stripe Error: builtins.AttributeError AttributeError: type object 'Subscription' has no attribute 'create'

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am getting this error in production only and in development like on local server it has no issues. I wonder what else I have to change in production because with all other payment integration I've never got issues different than development mode. It pops up stripe form and then green tick mark comes and after that I get this error.

View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            stripe_token = request.form['stripeToken']
            email = request.form['stripeEmail']

            try:
                customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                    email=email,
                    source=request.form['stripeToken']
                )

                subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
                    customer=customer.id,
                    plan="monthly",
                )
                student_id = profile_data.id
                student.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
                student.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id

                package = Package(
                    student_id=student_id,
                    stripe_id = customer.id,
                    student_email=request.form['stripeEmail'],
                    is_active=True,
                    package_type='monthly',
                    subscription_id=subscription.id
                )
                dbase.session.add(package)
                flash("You've successfully subscribed for monthly package.")
                dbase.session.commit()


            except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            # The card has been declined
                body = e.json_body
                err = body['error']

    return redirect(url_for('all_plans', key=key, amount=amount))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 265, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 265, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/connect/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/connect/GZ/server/views.py", line 1643, in monthly
    subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
AttributeError: type object 'Subscription' has no attribute 'create'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that you have an old version of Stripe's Python library installed in your production environment. The create method for Subscriptions was added on version 1.33.0 released on 2016-05-04. You'll want at least that version in production.